# "Fdisk" command not working Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to format an sd card WITH the Raspbian terminal to FAT32. I got everything working but when I went to change it from the default (Linux Filesystem) it didn't show up in the list. In fact, it's very, very different on Raspbian than on other Linux machines. I tried typing t then b, but apparently there aren't any letter format codes in Raspbian. I looked through all of the codes and couldn't find it. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SteveRobillard: that is the same question, without answers, so, no it will not answer Tyler's question.

Comment: @TylerSelden: On all my Pi-s, `fdisk` is more or less the same as on my slackware. Can you add the output of your `fdisk` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is not Raspbian, but the current contents of the SD card.

Fdisk is a tool for editing partition tables, and there are **two partition table formats** in popular use – "MBR" and "GPT" – which have completely different lists of partition type IDs. Fdisk is working correctly; it always shows the list that matches the current partition table format.

It seems your SD card currently uses the newer 'GPT' partition table format. In GPT, partition-type IDs are used to describe the *purpose* of the partition rather than correspond to any specific filesystem (e.g. the `Microsoft Basic Data` type is suitable for both FAT32 and NTFS).

However, generally SD cards and USB sticks use the older 'MBR' (aka 'DOS') partition table, which has the various `W95 FAT` partition-type IDs that you're looking for.

To switch the disk to the 'MBR' (DOS) partition table format, you can use these commands found in Fdisk's main menu:

```
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
```

(Note that these will automatically **remove** all partitions. If you want to convert a disk's partition table while keeping existing partitions, you will need to use the `gdisk` tool instead.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful.